# Unable to capture coordinates inside a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates

I need to capture coordinates on a click. But when I click inside `cont`, I get incorrect values. What could be the reason for this? It seems, that x-coordinate captured is correct, but Y coordinate is incorrect.

*HTML :*

```
<div id='first'> 
        <p> First</p>
        <div id='second'>
            <p>Second</p>
            <div id='cont'>
                    <span id='player'>  <img src='pro.png'/><strong>1</strong> </span>
                    <span id='player2'> <img src='pro.png'/><strong>2</strong> </span>
                    <span id='player3'> <img src='pro.png'/><strong>3</strong> </span>
                    <span id='player4'> <img src='pro.png'/><strong>4</strong> </span>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

jquery :

```
$('#cont').click(function(event) {
                var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
                if(count == 0) {
                    x1 = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
                    y1 = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
                    $('#cont').line(x1,y1,x1+1,y1+1,{color:"white", style: "dashed"});
                }           

});
```

Comment: I don't know what that `line` function is. Looks like an extension. It would help posters if they can quickly replicate your scenario without having to struggle to get it working. I suggest a JSFiddle, but modify your code so that they can replicate your problem as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parent()` clause is unnecessary if you are attempting to get the offset position in relation to `#cont`.

If you are trying to get the position in relation to `#second`, then continue to use the `parent()` clause.

Additionally, if you are trying to get the position within the `#first`, add *another* `parent()` clause.

If you are trying to get the position of the click within the context of the page itself (the 'global' position), use the 'pageX' and 'pageY' properties of the event.

```
$('#cont').click(function(event) {
    var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
    var x1 = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var y1 = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
    console.log("Local position: " + x1 + ", " + y1);
    var mouseXPos = event.pageX;
    var mouseYPos = event.pageY;   
    console.log("Global position: " + mouseXPos + ", " + mouseYPos);
});
```

I provide an example of each in Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ovL7ztob/2/

Comment: Why do we really need offset? Why doesn't `event.pageX` just return the actual `x` coordinate?

Comment: Not if you are trying to get the page (global) position. I've updated my answer to include both local and global position collection.